# Remembering Boolean information

Tags: vba, excel, boolean

I have a question regarding VBA and remember a boolean true/false value. It does not need to be remember after closing or saving, just when its open. But it does not seem to be remember this result.

I have the two checkboxes, one switches to the other when clicking one, but because one is loading a lot of data (checkbox 15) I dont want it to do it if the user accidently clicks on Checkbox 16.

```
Public Sub CheckBox1_Click()
Dim ACTUALLOADED As Boolean

If Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Check Box 15").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Check Box 16").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 0

   If ACTUALLOADED = False Then
   Sheet32.ListBox2_Empty
   Sheet32.ListBox1_Fill

    **DO SOME CODE**

    Sheet3.UpdateSOP
    ACTUALLOADED = True
     End If


Else
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Check Box 16").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1
   Sheet32.ListBox1_Empty
   Sheet32.ListBox2_Fill


End If
End Sub
```

When the checkbox is clicked for the first time, ACTUALLOADED = False, so it runs the code.

However at the end the code makes ACTUALLOADED = TRUE, but it forgets it when I click the same checkbox again.

It's like it does not remember the Booleans TRUE/FALSE. How can I make this happen?

Comment: Can you supply more code, more like the entire sub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Public` would solve your problem I think.

Take `ACTUALLOADED` out of the sub and declare it as public:

```
Public ACTUALLOADED As Boolean
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Static option when defining your variable so instead of

```
Dim ACTUALLOADED As Boolean
```

you would use

```
Static ACTUALLOADED as Boolean
```

This will keep ACTUALLOADED value between calls.

but like @JLILI Amen said you could use a public deceleration at the module level not Sub/Function level.